# Django two separate project under one domain as sub directories

Tags: django, nginx

I am trying to config Two separate Django project under one domain name as subdirectories,
So I can open project1 as https://mycompany.example.com/project1 and project 2 as https://mycompany.example.com/project2

here is my Nginx configuration

```
server {
    server_name mycompany.example.com;

    location ~/project1/static {
        alias /home/username/project1/static;
    }

    location ~/project1/media {
        alias /home/username/project1/media;
    }

    location /project1/ {
        rewrite ^/project1/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /project1;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/project1.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }

    location ~/project2/static {
        alias /home/username/project2/static;
    }

    location ~/project2/media {
        alias /home/username/project2/media;
    }

    location /project2/ {
        rewrite ^/project2/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /project2;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/project2.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycompany.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycompany.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

This configuration works and I can open it as I mentioned it above, here the problem is static and the media location is not working, is there any workaround to make it work, I request you to please guide me to achieve it. It will be very helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you configure two locations: /static1 pointing to ~/project1/static and /static2 pointing to ~/project2/static ?

Comment: @NicolasAppriou Thanks for your reply...I tried but it does not worked

Comment: Well, this is what you need to investigate... Why it didn't worked. With what you gave us, I can't help.

Comment: You have to align `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL` in each project's `settings.py` with a location that matches nginx.

Comment: @Melvyn Thanks for your reply, can you provide some example. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution for my problem

***Nginx config***

```
server {
    server_name mycompany.example.com;

    location /project1/static {
        alias /home/username/project1/static;
    }

    location /project1/media {
        alias /home/username/project1/media;
    }

    location /project1/ {
        rewrite ^/project1/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /project1;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/project1.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }

    location /project2/static {
        alias /home/username/project2/static;
    }

    location /project2/media {
        alias /home/username/project2/media;
    }

    location /project2/ {
        rewrite ^/project2/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /project2;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/project2.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycompany.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycompany.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

In Django the complete set of url must be `{% url '<URL>' %}`, static url must be `{% static '<path>' %}`

***project1 settings.py***

```
STATIC_URL = '/project1/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/project1/media/'
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/project1/'
```

***project2 settings.py***

```
STATIC_URL = '/project2/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/project2/media/'
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/project2/'
```

This worked for me, so now I can config two or many different Django projects under one domain name as subdirectories. Hope it will help someone... Thanks